# What's the meaning of "out of being an ass"?

Tags: meaning

The actual sentence is: 
"Keep in mind that you can't apologize your way out of being an ass."
What does it mean?

Comment: "Being an ass" is being really annoying and, usually, self-centered, being totally insensitive to the needs and feelings of other people.

Comment: The point, I think, is that, whereas some difficult social situations can safely be navigated by using a combination of caution and humility and (in the worst case) profuse apologies, the underlying condition of assness is nonnegotiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parseing the sentence differently, and it makes more sense.  To "Apologise your way out of" a problem is to make a bad situation better by apologising for an earlier mistake.  The sentence is saying that it is of no use to apologise if people still think you are an ass.

Comment: No, it is saying that apologising does not magically transform people's present perceptions about you (based on your poor track record). OP's quote is from _Rework: Change the Way You Work Forever_  by _Jason Fried, David Heinemeier_ .  Two sentences after OP's is: 'Everything you do before things go wrong matters far more than the actual words you use to apologise.'

Comment: It's like "If you put lipstick on a pig - it's still a pig."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I've edited my post so hopefully it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom.

"He made his way out of the church."

"She argued her way out of receiving a parking fine."

"He wheedled his way out of doing the washing up."

"She's so weak, she couldn't fight her way out of a paper bag."

etc.